# Getting the default font size in TinyMCE 5 to get set in the editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

In my TinyMCE 5 editor it looks like a font size of 11 pt is selected by default, but I see when checking the source that actually no font size is added to the source unless I select a font size.

As a result, the font size is saved posts is small - it just depends on the default font size of the page it's displayed on.

Is there a way of getting the editor to actually use a default font size in the HTML being created?

Thanks.